# JsReport not rendering docxCheckbox

Tags: docker, docx, jsreport

I have a Docker Image where jsReport is rendering a custom doxc file to a pdf. I have normal string values like firstname and lastname + some checkboxes depending on previous user input.

Evening works fine for the string values, but the checkboxes will not get rendered.

[image: String values]

[image: Boolean values]

After rendering, it looks like this:

[image: String rendered]

[image: Boolean rendered]

The data looks like this:
{
"customer": {
"fullName": "John Doe",
"birthDate": "10.10.1999",
"companyRegistrationNumber": " / AB123456",
"fullAddress": "Street 1234 B5",
"email": "mail@support.com"
},
"date": "11.09.2022",
"ready": true
}

It is rendering something, it even uses the "ready" value because it displays the same string as "true", but it is not displaying a checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docxCheckbox helper call needs to be placed in the title of the word checkbox.

See the documentation
https://jsreport.net/learn/docx#forms

And the demo
https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/DtnCaXMs

[image: https://jsreport.net/learn/docx#forms]

Comment: Thank you very much!
I could not find the menu for the checkbox, now its working!!!

Answer (score 0):

The property menu is not available with the right-click menu. It is only in the developers tab

[image: Menu]